# Discretizing Bates SVJ Model to simulate paths

Tags: options, programming, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, stochastic-volatility

I am trying to simulate a path for Bates Stochastic-Volatility-Jump model. It has the following dynamics:

[image]

I've managed to implement the Heston model by following Gatheral's books the Volatility Surface and have the following discretisation for the underlying:

[image]

As the Bates model essentially is an extension of the Heston model by adding jumps my problem is with regards to how to discretize the jump-part.

My implementation is done in Matlab so if anyone has suggestions for how I would go about implementing the jump-part (meaning the Poisson process) I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Hi. Can you describe what you are having trouble with exactly? $q$ is a Poisson process (usually denoted $N_t$), such that $dq$ figures the number of jump over an infinitesimal interval. To sample from $dq$ you draw from a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda dt$ e.g. $\texttt{dq = poissrnd(lambda*dt, numberOfSamples, 1)}$

Comment: I think that essentially my problem is with regards to intuition for the Poisson process but that's why I'm here. So when Ive drawn dq, obtaining a certain number of jumps over an infinitesimal interval, how do I determine when a jump should occur in my path simulation..?
If I simulate a path for the process over a year with dt=1/365 and I find that dq=3, could I just do that 3/365 is the probability over that period of time that a jump occurs and draw a random variable between 0,1 and if that random variable is less than 3/365 a jump occurs wherein I then sample the size for the jump?

Comment: Let's say you opt for an Euler discretisation scheme (in the log returns) so that you get
$$ \delta (\ln S_t) = (\mu - \lambda \bar{k} - \frac{1}{2}v_{t_i}^+) \delta t + \sqrt{v_{t_i}^+} \delta W_t + \ln(1+k) \delta q$$
So assuming you stand at $t$ and want to simulate up at $t+\delta t$, on top of what you need if there were no jumps, you need to simulate (i) the number of jumps over $[t,t+\delta t[$ i.e. $\delta q$ as just described; (ii) multiply it by the jump size $\ln(1+k)$, which is normally distributed as per your equations.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me :)